# Why does gitlab-ci default to using git clone for each job instead of building a docker image first?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

Gitlab-ci's default mode is to use git clone in every job in a pipeline.
This is time-consuming, especially since after cloning we need to install/update all dependencies.
I'd like to flip the order of our pipelines, and start with git clone + docker build, then run all subsequent jobs using that image without cloning and rebuilding for each job.

Am I missing something?
Is there any reason that I'd want to clone the repo separately for each job if I already have an image with the current code?

Comment: you can stop the runner from cloning everytime by this [setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#git-strategy).

Comment: @Narro thanks. I’m aware of the setting, the question is a little bit higher-level than that. In a modern, docker based ci pipeline is there any advantage to be gained using the default behavior over build first then test.

Comment: can you just set a test stage, using your built image and running your test jobs? @chananelb

Comment: Yes, that’s what I’m doing, I’m just trying to understand if doing so has any downsides that I’m missing.

Comment: it's ok, every stage is designed individually. you can even create multi test stages(or other stages) running in multi runners(specified by tags). just using the way suit for your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not missing anything. If you know what you are doing, you don't need to clone your repo for each stage in your pipeline. If you set the `GIT_STRATEGY` variable to `none`, your test jobs, or whatever they are, will run faster and you can simply run your docker pull commands and the tests that you need. Just make sure that you use the correct docker images, even if you start many parallel jobs. You could for example use `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` as part of the name of the docker image.

As to why GitLab defaults to using git clone, my guess is that this is the least surprising behavior. If you imagine someone new to GitLab and new to CI, it will be much easier for them to get up and running if each job simply clones the whole repo. You also have to remember that not everyone builds docker images in their jobs. I would guess that the most common way this is set up is either with programming languages that doesn't need to be compiled, for example `python`, or that there is a `build` job that produces binaries, and then a `test` job that runs the binaries. They can then use `artifacts` to send the binaries from the build job to the test job.

This is easy and it works. When people then realize that a lot of the time of their test jobs is spent just cloning the repository, they might look into how to change the `GIT_STRATEGY`, and to do other things to optimize their particular build.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons of using a CI is to execute your repo in a fresh state. This cannot be done if you skip the git clone process in certain jobs. A job may modify the repo's state by deleting its file or generating new ones; only the `artifacts` which are explicitly documented in the pipeline should be shared between jobs-nothing else.

Comment: Thanks! As noted on the question I’m considering using a job in stage 1 to build a docker image from the fresh repo, and then using that image for all subsequent stages on that same fresh repo baked into a docker image. That way I don’t need to double check and reinstall the same dependencies for each stage. Artifacts will be used as usual but each subsequent stage will be much quicker. Does that make sense? I’m essentially looking for overlooked downsides to this

Comment: Well images are self-contained so there's no harm in sharing those (which is why GitLab CI uses Docker images for jobs). In order to share them, you'll need to push the image to your local GitLab CI Docker registry in the first job, and then pull it on subsequent jobs.